# Hibernate: Obtaining Map with a column's value as "key", and as "value" a list of rows containing "key"

Tags: java, hibernate

Good afternoon,

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity(name = "t_test")
public class Test {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
....
```

I basically want to create a query/criteria that returns just one Map, where the keys are the distinct values of Test.type, and the values of the map are Lists of Test objects with the corresponding type property. 
E.g: Map>

Can this be done in one query? Right now I'm just fetching everything and creating the map by code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a ResultTransformer to create and return the map, but it wouldn't be much different than what you're doing now. The code would just be in a different place.

To produce the `Map<String, List<Test>>`, you need to load all the test entries from the database anyway. There's no processing related to the map creation that can be moved closer to the DB except maybe ordering by `type`. You basically have to make the map in your code.